# Root Cause of ERR_OUT_OF_RANGE (getSystemErrorName, TLSWrap.onStreamRead)

Tags: node.js

We have a complex application that has been throwing the following unhandled-exception more and more frequently:

```
RangeError [ERR_OUT_OF_RANGE]:
The value of "err" is out of range. It must be a negative integer. Received 6
at Object.getSystemErrorName (util.js:220:11)
at errnoException (internal/errors.js:463:21)
at TLSWrap.onStreamRead (internal/stream_base_commons.js:201:27
```

That's all the info we get. I'm on day 2 of researching root cause, and I've got nothing. I've updated from Node 10 to 12, updated mongoose drivers, etc but no luck.

Then I patched `getSystemErrorName` to never throw - hoping the original stream's error handler would be more helpful:

```
var util = require('util');
var _getSystemErrorName = util.getSystemErrorName;
util.getSystemErrorName = function(code){
  try{ return _getSystemErrorName.apply(util, arguments); }
  catch(e){ return String("ERRCD"+code); }
};
```

But now I'm getting no errors.

Any ideas how to figure out what stream or package is emitting `6` as the error code?

Comment: Have you tried printing the stack trace in `process.on('uncaughtException')` or `process.on('unhandledRejection');`? Maybe that would help

Comment: Yes, `on('uncaughtException')` is how we got the stack listed above. We also have rejection reporting but nothing has come from those.